# nvd3 not loading json

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I've done a nvd3 graphic, but it does not load the json.

What changes do I have to do in nvd3? I'm a little lost... sorry.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart();
  var fitScreen = false;
  var width = 600;
  var height = 400;
  var zoom = 1;

  chart.useInteractiveGuideline(true);
  chart.xAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse);
      //.tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

  chart.yAxis
      .axisLabel('Alumnos')
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
      .attr('perserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMid')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .datum(datos);

  setChartViewBox();
  resizeChart();

  // These resizes both do the same thing, and require recalculating the chart
  //nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  //nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart1 svg').call(chart) });
  nv.utils.windowResize(resizeChart);

  d3.select('#zoomIn').on('click', zoomIn);
  d3.select('#zoomOut').on('click', zoomOut);


  function setChartViewBox() {
    var w = width * zoom,
        h = height * zoom;

    chart
        .width(w)
        .height(h);

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + w + ' ' + h)
      .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);
  }

  function zoomOut() {
    zoom += .25;
    setChartViewBox();
  }

  function zoomIn() {
    if (zoom <= .5) return;
    zoom -= .25;
    setChartViewBox();
  }

  // This resize simply sets the SVG's dimensions, without a need to recall the chart code
  // Resizing because of the viewbox and perserveAspectRatio settings
  // This scales the interior of the chart unlike the above
  function resizeChart() {
    var container = d3.select('#chart1');
    var svg = container.select('svg');

    if (fitScreen) {
      // resize based on container's width AND HEIGHT
      var windowSize = nv.utils.windowSize();
      svg.attr("width", windowSize.width);
      svg.attr("height", windowSize.height);
    } else {
      // resize based on container's width
      var aspect = chart.width() / chart.height();
      var targetWidth = parseInt(container.style('width'));
      svg.attr("width", targetWidth);
      svg.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
    }
  };
  return chart;
});
```

And the json is:

```
                [
    {
        "date": "20140701",
        "Baja": 0,
        "No admitido": 3851,
        "Pre-inscrito": 0,
        "Admitido": 0,
        "En reserva": 0,
        "Alta": 0,
        "Inactivo": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "20140701",
        "Baja": 0,
        "No admitido": 3851,
        "Pre-inscrito": 2468,
        "Admitido": 0,
        "En reserva": 0,
        "Alta": 0,
        "Inactivo": 0
    }
]
```

I was looking for it but all I found is to modify the json. I did it, but it did not work. I prefer to preserve this json format if it is possible, it simplifies the process at all for me.

Thank u so much!

Comment: I don't see a single reference to your json in the graph code. How can it load it if you never tell it to? you're missing a call to `d3.json(` or something similar.

Comment: Creo q estas colocando mal el formato del json, pues creo q quieres hacer una grafica de lineas pero no tienes X y Y, pues almenos en el json no defines q dato va ser X y que dato Y, con el formato de json q tienes no entiendo como la quieres hacer.

te dejo este codigo lo miras y me comentas mas info para ayudarte http://codepen.io/CristianG540/pen/Ggqjdm

Comment: Hi @CristianG. The json is longer... what I want to do is 7 lines (baja, no admitido, pre-inscrito, admitido...) and date in X. Thanks a lot! Gracias ;)

Comment: I think the problem is here... it does not parse the first value in every json item (x) which is the date. Is this ok? chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse);

Comment: :P creo que usare otro plugin de d3, se llama c3.js dame un momento y te mandare un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Mira creo que esto es lo que quieres :3

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: datos,
        keys: {
          x    : 'date', // it's possible to specify 'x' when category axis
          value: ['Baja', 'No admitido', 'Pre-inscrito', 'Admitido', 'En reserva', 'Alta', 'Inactivo']
        }
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/CristianG540/pen/bNegqV

Comment: He probado con el c3, pero nada... no consigo resultados y voy contrarreloj :) Cual es mejor, c3 o nvd3? o hay alguno más? Mil gracias por la ayuda Cristian!

Comment: para mi c3 es mejor, lo estan actualizando muy seguido y la libreria en si es muy modular, dime q necesitas y te puedo ayudar mas, el ejemplo q te pase no te sirvió ?